Extract CSV data from SQL Server column
I am looking for some assistance with handling some badly formatted data. I know similar questions have been asked but I haven't found any answers that pertain to this specific use case. My data flow goes from SQL Server to SSIS, so any method can be utilized to handle it.
I have a table that contains a few columns, one of which contains a nested CSV, which always contains the same number of fields, but uses a space as the row end and also has spaces within the data itself.
Some sample data would look like this:
Person  House   Pets
-------------------------------------------------------------
person1 house1  "dog,rex,4 cat,sally,7 lizard,mr scales,4"
person2 house2  "fish,wanda,10 dog,bud,8"

What I would like to do is split out this CSV data into a table like this:
Person  House   Species Name        Age
------------------------------------------
person1 house1  dog     rex         4
person1 house1  cat     sally       7
person1 house1  lizard  mr scales   4
person2 house2  fish    wanda       10
person2 house2  dog     bud         8

What makes it difficult (maybe impossible) to achieve in SQL is the fact that the line ending character is also used in the data itself (see: mr scales).
What I am looking for is either:

a solution in T-SQL that I have overlooked or
a tool within the SSIS toolbox that can handle this

If the answer falls under #2 and is a Script Task, I would appreciate some guidance as I am not experienced with C#/VB
Thanks in advance, please let me know if I am missing any crucial or helpful details here.

The fact that you can have a delimiter inside your data and it's not scale, is a significant fundamental problem. The data should never have got anywhere near the database in that state.

Can any of those delimited values be missing values? For example, could you have a value like 'rabbit,mittens hamster,george,1'?

Can you also have a breed that has a space in it? Honsetly, the more I think about it, the more I think your data is fundamentally broken.

I don't see any feasible way to do this in SQL alone. Is this stable data (ie no new records) or do you have the possiblity to refactor the data generation process? If yes, I'd strongly suggest you to transform your data once with external tools into your desired format and (if necessary) update the process generating new data to use that new format.

@ThomA there will be no missing values, always the same number of commas, and only the Name field will potentially have spaces

I really recommend that you fix your design here; that be in the database and the CSV like original data. As you are using a delimiter that also appears in the data (a white space), parsing your data becomes very difficult, as you have no idea if the character (the whitespace) is a row delimiter or not.
For the solution here, I make the assumptions that no values can have a comma as part of its value (if it does your data is so fundamentally broken that it's useless), a breed cannot have a space, and that all "pets" will always have a Breed, Name and Age. If they don't then this won't work (and I would again suggest your data is fundamentally broken).
I use STRING_SPLIT here and it's oridinal parameter; that is not available in SQL Server 2019 (only 2022+), however, I'm not in a position right now to use an older solution like DelimitedSplit8k_LEAD. You will need to use a different splitter than provides the ordinal position of the string (the oridinal position is important).
I split on commas here, which get most of the data right. Then I split the rows that will be a combination of Age and breed. Finally, I recombine the rows using conditional aggregation based on the row number and integer maths:
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (Person varchar(30),
                            House varchar(30),
                            Pets varchar(8000));
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (Person,
                           House,
                           Pets)
VALUES ('person1','house1','dog,rex,4 cat,sally,7 lizard,mr scales,4'),
       ('person2','house2','fish,wanda,10 dog,bud,8');
GO

WITH HalfNormalised AS(
    SELECT YT.Person,
           YT.House,
           ISNULL(SSS.Value,SSC.Value) AS Value,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YT.Person, YT.House ORDER BY SSC.ordinal, SSS.ordinal) AS RN
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT
         CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Pets,',',1) SSC
         OUTER APPLY STRING_SPLIT(CASE WHEN SSC.ordinal = 3 OR ((SSC.Ordinal +1) % 3 = 0 AND SSC.Ordinal > 3) THEN SSC.value END,' ',1) SSS)
SELECT HF.Person,
       HF.House,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN % 3 = 1 THEN value END) AS Breed,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN % 3 = 2 THEN value END) AS Name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN % 3 = 0 THEN value END) AS Age
FROM HalfNormalised HF
GROUP BY HF.Person,
         HF.House,
         (HF.RN-1) / 3;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;

db<>fiddle
